# Shader map along normals inside cycles from center to the periphery of an object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, shader-nodes, masking, vector-mapping

Hello Blender Community,

I have an object that consists of a simple sphere with geo nodes based tentacles applied to it. I want to create a mask with a color ramp that alters the color beginning from the center to the periphery. So that the color changes from the base to the tips.

I know that there is a possibility to use the trace curves parameter from the curves info node. But since I am using geometry nodes I need another solution.

I'd be glad for your help.
Kind regards